# How to require a pass within the source code

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am working on a optimization pass and I need to remove a few dead basic blocks in a loop. I know that the pass `unreachableblockelim` can do the job but how do I require it to execute in the middle of my pass? That is, without using opt command line interface:

```
opt -load myOptPass.dylib -unreachableblockelim ir.bc -o ir2.bc
```

Is that even possible? I couldn't find anything similar to what I am trying to achieve in the llvm source code.

Comment: A pass is just code. If you want to run that pass in the middle of yours, you can create an instance of its class and call its run().

Comment: Hi @arnt, thanks for the answer. My question is more related to how do I do that? Specifically, how do I instantiate the **unreachableblockelim** pass?

Comment: It turns out that instantiating a pass was simpler than I thought. Thanks, arnt!

Comment: Oh, I was typing that answer while you commented. Well, it's nice when problems evaporate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLVM contains two pass managers at the moment. The pass you want uses the new one (characterised by the pass inheriting PassInfoMixin), and using it in a new-PM pass requires including its header file in your pass' .cpp file:

```
#include "llvm/CodeGen/UnreachableBlockElim.h"
```

Your pass will contain a function named run(), which perhaps looks like this:

```
PreservedAnalyses MyPAss::run(Function &F, FunctionAnalysisManager &FAM) {
  // some of your code goes here

  UnreachableBlockElimPass ube;
  ube.run(F, FAM);

  // more of your code here
}
```

If your pass uses the old pass manager (characterised by inheriting FunctionPass, ModulePass etc) then it's a little more involved, because you need to provide that FunctionAnalysisManager yourself. In that case I'd start by migrating to the new way.